# Inconsistent information in Active Directory Members and Member Of properties

Tags: active-directory, users, groups

I'm trying to get a list of the members of a group in Active Directory. I'm using LDAP queries, but I think that's not relevant. I've found what I believe to be an inconsistency in Active Directory's group membership information:

A security group `G` has been created with Global scope. Viewing `G`'s properties using the AD Users and Computers MMC Snap-in shows **three** users, `A` `B` `C` on the Members tab.

However, on viewing the User properties of `A` `B` and `C`, only `A` and `B` have `G` listed on the 'Member Of' tab - `G` is *not* present on the 'Member Of' tab of user `C`.

**How can it be that a user is in the Members list of a group, but that group is *not* in the 'Member Of' list for that user?**

<sub>(note that the group `G` is *not* any user's primary group)</sub>

(*I originally thought this was an LDAP querying problem, but it isn't: the queries accurately report the information in Active Directory, and it's that that's inconsistent*)

Comment: Is it the user's primary group?

Comment: Just for grins - which is correct according to the AD toolset? (like ADUC)

Comment: @uSlackr thanks, that tipped me off that it's actually AD giving me the results I don't understand, rather than LDAP as such. Updated the q.

Comment: @Shane no, it's a freshly created group. I've updated the q to be about AD rather than LDAP, since that seems to be the root of it.

Answer (score 2):

There can be an issue getting complete results if you are querying a group that contains entries from multiple AD domains (global vs universal groups).  There is more on the topic [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/f5ec5ed6-a909-46df-a52d-97aeb2b5c29e)

(Note: on the linked page, I see wingding fonts in the middle of the post from Che.  Here they are converted to a real font:

> - At a DC for the domain that contains the user, memberOf for the user is complete with respect to group membership in that domain; however, memberOf does not contain the user's membership in domain local and global groups in other domains.
> - At a GC server, memberOf for the user is complete with respect to all universal group memberships.

)

Comment: Thanks for that link, although I am slightly getting out of my depth I think :) I'm getting the feeling the best thing to do is just find the group and read its members, rather than relying on `memberOf` - does that seem reasonable?